# Laravel 5 password reset

Tags: php, laravel

How can I make password reset in laravel 5? I'm Laravel begginer, I wan't to show form with email input. When click submit, send email with password change link, thanks in advance ;)

Comment: This is in the standard Laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-passwords

Comment: @Ben thank you, and second question how can I minify php strings? For exampel I have string: "Laravel 5 password reset" how can I make "laravel-5-password-reset" ?

Comment: Ask that question on stack overflow :) Or edit this question to ask that.

Comment: read the documentation `str_slug` http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-slug

Comment: @Ben I'm created same as in tutorial and when I'm go to http://example.com/password/reset it redirects me to example.com/home

Comment: @EvaldasL. Try logging out first -- you can't reset your password if you're logged in.

Comment: @Ben ok, now when I go to example.com/password/reset I've got this: `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` and `NotFoundHttpException in ResetsPasswords.php line 65:`

Comment: Ah it's because I'm going without token. How can I generate it ?

Comment: @EvaldasL. look at this https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.0/resources/views/auth and https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.0/resources/views/auth